# AngularJS - Splitting JSON into two even groups

Tags: json, angularjs

I am getting a list of names that varies in length depending on the number of employees.

```
 $http({
        url: '/SharedData/ClockInList',
        method: "POST",
        params: {Date: currentday}
    }).success(function (data) {

    })
```

I need a way upon success to split my JSON into two even length lists. What I am thinking is a way to count the number of results and then say from 0 to that number put in $scope.A and the remaining in $scope.B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to partition the list:

```
$scope.lotsOfData = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ];

$scope.listA = $scope.lotsOfData.filter( function(value,index){
    return index % 2 == 0;
});

$scope.listB = $scope.lotsOfData.filter( function(value,index){
    return index % 2 == 1;
});
```

or [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
$scope.listC = $scope.lotsOfData.slice(0, $scope.lotsOfData.length / 2 + 1);

$scope.listD = $scope.lotsOfData.slice($scope.lotsOfData.length / 2 + 1);
```

```js
angular.module('MyModule', [])

.controller('MyController', function( $scope ) {
  
  $scope.lotsOfData = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ];
  
  $scope.listA = $scope.lotsOfData.filter( function(value,index){
    return index % 2 == 0;
  });
  
  $scope.listB = $scope.lotsOfData.filter( function(value,index){
    return index % 2 == 1;
  });
  
  $scope.listC = $scope.lotsOfData.slice(0, $scope.lotsOfData.length / 2 + 1);
  
  $scope.listD = $scope.lotsOfData.slice($scope.lotsOfData.length / 2 + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='MyModule' ng-controller='MyController'>
  <p>{{listA || json}}</p>
  <p>{{listB || json}}</p>
  <p>{{listC || json}}</p>
  <p>{{listD || json}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is close to what I need but in ListA I would need 1,2,3,4,5 and ListB would be 6,7,8,9

Answer (score 0):

You can use Underscore.JS to split the data using groupBy. 
groupBy returns object and if you want to convert to an array use  _.toArray()

```
var data = ["1", "7", "8", "9", "11", "12"];
var splitData = _.groupBy(data, function(element, index){
  return Math.floor(index/2);
});

splitData = _.toArray(splitData);
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is close to what I need but in ListA I would need 1,2,3,4,5 and ListB would be 6,7,8,9

You have a few options, for loop or use filter / some other library to do the grouping, but what you'll need to do is get the count of the items and then use the index of your item < count / 2 into one group and >= count / 2 into a second group.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

```
$http({
    url: '/SharedData/ClockInList',
    method: "POST",
    params: {Date: currentday}
}).success(function (data) {
    group1 = []; // these need to be declared on scope or controller or somewhere
    group2 = [];
    var count = data.length;
    angular.forEach(data, function(item, key) {
        if (key <= count / 2) {
            group1.push(item);
        } else {
            group2.push(item);
        }
    }
})
```